# How do I share map links in the new version of Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

The new vector-based version of [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com) seems to have lost the ability to easily share a map location or point of interest with someone else. It seems there are some Google+ sharing features, but I can't find a way to email a point of interest to someone.

Does anyone know how I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the settings (gear icon) in the bottom right corner. You then get the option to "Share and embed map":

[image: Gear Icon menu]

This gives you the URL for the map (optionally shortened):

[image: Share URL dialog]

More info...
https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?p=newmaps_shorturl&rd=1

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I don't know why I didn't spot that.